# XML not parsing entity references?

Tags: xml, vbscript, character, entities

I'm using VBScript to pass values into an XML document.

For a specific node I am splitting a string and trying to write each element to a new line.

```
    1. Set nNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode("//Parent/Child/Subchild")
    2. nodeString = ""
    3. splitString = split(originalString, ";")
    4. For i = 1 To (arrLength(splitString))
    5. nodeString = nodeString & splitString(i) & "&#13;&#10;"
    6. Next
    7. nNode.text = nodeString
```

However when I create the xml file the text prints as

> "blahblah&#13;&#10;blahblah&#13;&#10;blahblah"

instead of

> blahblah
>
> blahblah
>
> blahblah

Can't figure out why it's not recognising the character entities

**===EDIT===**

Using the like of vbNewLine or vbCrLf affect the formatting inside the XML document itself when I open it in a text editor. So is there any way I can preserve the new lines when I display it in a browser? (I'm using IE for this)
I have xml:Space="preserve" inside the root node on the page but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you tried `& vbNewLine` instead of `& "&#13;&#10;"`?

Comment: vbNewLine or vbCrLf don't seem to affect the formatting at all.

Comment: when you write `nodeString` back to the node, the ampersands are encoded as `&amp;`, so `&#13;&#10;` becomes `&amp;#13;&amp;#10;`. What are you trying to achieve anyway (i.e. why do you believe you need those newlines)?

Comment: Does it matter why I need it on new lines? It's mostly just for the sake of readability of the document. The values are being added to a table using an XLS stylesheet, so having them display on new lines within the table just looks better than having them tacked end to end.